# Is there a way to count the number of keys in a json object directly in angular expressions?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to show the number of keys in a json object on a web page. So, is there a way to calculate the count directly in the angular expression?

For example,

JSON:

```
$scope.json = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", key3: "value3"}
```

For this 'json', there are three keys. I want to get the count of keys directly in an angular expression without calculating it in the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to use a custom filter like this:

template:

```
{{json | numKeys}}
```

filter:

```
app.filter('numKeys', function() {
    return function(json) {
        var keys = Object.keys(json)
        return keys.length;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to some extent. But now, if I want to compare the number of keys in ng-if. How to do it?

Comment: where is ng-if? and compare what and what parameter?

Comment: In the template, I need to show a table if the number of keys in that "json" is greater than zero.

Comment: <p ng-if="(json|numKeys) > 0">Hello {{name}}!</p>

Comment: <table ng-if="(json|numKeys) > 0">

Comment: Arrow functions can spruce this up into a 1 liner. `app.filter('numKeys', () => json => Object.keys(json).length);`

Answer (score 0):

Some `hacky` way would be to do the following:

```js
howManyKeys = {
    a: 'Do',
    b: 'I',
    c: 'have?',
}
```

1. If you only want to use it a few times:

```
This object has {{ (howManyKeys | keyValue).length }} keys
<span *ngIf="(howManyKeys | keyValue).length > 2">That's more than 2!</span>
```

2. If you only want to show it on many spots:

```
<span *ngFor="let howManyKeysLength of [(howManyKeys | keyValue).length]">
   This object has {{howManyKeysLength}} keys.
   <span *ngIf="howManyKeysLength > 2">That's more than 2!</span>
   <span *ngIf="howManyKeysLength < 5">Less than 5!</span>
</span>
```

This can be useful when you don't want to add a service.